# Is it possible to downgrade laravel 8.0 to 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was doing my client project. He told me he has Unlimited Cpanel purchased. so i just did my project on latest Laravel version. Now when i got his cpanel it has php version 5.4. What can i do now?
i was thinking about downgrading both laravel and php but will it support all features? Any help.

Comment: if your hosting supports only php 5.4, then change hosting, there is big security issue in both php and laravel on those versions since they are no longed supported...  on CPanel you should have an icon with "select PHP version"

Comment: and a side note, there is no tagged version of Laravel 8, it hasn't been released yet

Answer (score 1):

There are likely to be security vulnerabilities in that version of PHP and Laravel. The solution here is to get the client to upgrade his server infrastructure.